# ORDER BY по вложенному запросу

Tags: sql, access, ms-access

Как отсортировать запрос по количеству рейсов?

```
SELECT А.Город, А.Название,
    (SELECT COUNT(Р.АэропортОтправления)
    FROM Рейсы AS Р
    WHERE А.Название = Р.АэропортОтправления)
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(Р.АэропортПрибытия)
    FROM Рейсы AS Р
    WHERE А.Название = Р.АэропортПрибытия) AS [Количество рейсов]
FROM Аэропорты AS А
ORDER BY ???
```

`ORDER BY [Количество рейсов]` Выводит окно с вводом данных, которое ни на что не влияет

Comment: `ORDER BY 3` тоже не работает, хотя с 1 и 2 сортирует

Comment: вам не кажется, что тут нужен джойн таблиц и группировка?

Comment: согласен,   Аэропорты as A join Рейсы аs  R1 join Рейсы as  R2 и группировка будет лучше. Но нужно проверять - может помешать INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обернуть

```
select * from (
  SELECT А.Город , А.Название
    ,((SELECT COUNT(Р.АэропортОтправления)
       FROM Рейсы AS Р
       WHERE А.Название = Р.АэропортОтправления
      )
    +
      (SELECT COUNT(Р.АэропортПрибытия)
       FROM Рейсы AS Р
       WHERE А.Название = Р.АэропортПрибытия)     
    ) AS [Количество рейсов]
FROM Аэропорты AS А
)x
ORDER BY  [Количество рейсов]
```